# Can we access the kraken config object in dust template?

Tags: node.js, express, dust.js, kraken.js

My Kraken config in config.json

```
envConfig : {
     prod : {
        host : "....",
        desc : "..."
    },
     qa : {
         host : "....",
        desc : "..."
    },
}
```

Can I access this in my dust template as I wanted to dynamically populate my list or would I have to add it again in my context object for the template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used ContextDump helper to find that the config is not accessible.I think it makes sense too as we should not expose the configuration information to the client side via dust